# Converting date to user timezone in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I am having some problems converting dates to UTC and then back to user time zone.

Since I already have a lot of users I am getting their timezones using the timezone gem https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone and I get results like this: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)".

The problem appears when I ask them for a particular date/time and I want to add the timezone to it ("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") and save it in the DB in UTC.

I am getting the date using jQuery UI Datepicker and I get it in this format: "Sunday, Oct 13, 2013" and the time in this format "12:00 am".

After this I use DateTime.strptime("user input", "%A, %b %e, %Y %I:%M %P") to convert it to datetime.

My question is how can I set the user timezone which is stored in the DB as string "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" for this date?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to format the time zone and add it to the user input string and then parse it as shown below:

```
user_input += ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").formatted_offset
DateTime.strptime(user_input, "%A, %b %e, %Y %I:%M %P%:z")
```

Comment: I tested this but in_time_zone changes the hour:

`DateTime.parse('Sunday, Oct 13, 2013 01:00 pm', '%A, %b %e, %Y %I:%M %P').in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
 => Sun, 13 Oct 2013 06:00:00 PDT -07:00`

I want to keep the same hour (01:00 pm) as in the above example.

Comment: @AlexPanait See my edited post, hopefully that works better for you